# Make availability for Windows

Tags: windows, makefile

I see in this [link](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/) that I can create a Makefile, so that it can conveniently be run by using the command `make`. Is this kind of Makefile also available for execution in Windows, and if not, how can it be turned into something that can be executed on Windows?

Comment: Have yoou tried this?: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22make+for+windows%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at **[CMake](http://www.cmake.org/)**. It is a **cross-platform**, open-source build system.
For a windows specific solution, there is also **[NMake](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930369.aspx)**.

Comment: Do these tools allow me to write the Makefile in a "normal" way (i.e. the way as specified in the link), or do I have to modify the Makefile in some way?

Comment: @JJBeck CMake generates native makefiles, so yeah, it is a little different but has the same content as the makefile in your example. [CMake FAQ](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ).